# How to convert the AES-256 key and Initial vector with the public RSA Key (Shared by third party system)

Tags: integration

**Problem**

How to convert the AES-256 key and Initial vector with the public RSA Key (Shared by third party system)

**Requirement**

1. Randomly generate a AES-256 key.
2. Randomly generate an IV.
3. Encrypt the json with the AES key and IV, base64-encode it, and set it as the request
   body.
4. Encrypt the AES key with the public RSA key and base64-encode it
5. Encrypt the IV with the public RSA key and base64-encode it

**Implementation**

From the above requirement, I am able to implement the point 1, 2, and 3. Now the technical challenge which we are facing here is, how to convert the AES-256 key and initial vector with the public RSA Key shared by third party system?

**Approach one**

I tried with below code and getting following error

> System.SecurityException: Invalid Crypto Key

```
Blob encryptedData = Crypto.sign(‘RSA‘, ‘AEX-256 Key’ ‘AEXThirdPartyPublicKey );
```

**Approach two**

Tried below, however client is getting

> "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: too much data for RSA
> block"

Answer (score 0):

I could able to implement as below:- By using Open SSL use below comment to get the module and exponent openssl rsa -pubin -in pubkey.txt -text -noout (Remove (:) from Module ...

https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/18031/the-modulus-of-rsa-public-key

public AEXResponse invokeAEXAPI(AEXRequest aexRequest)  {

```
    API_Utils_Logger logger;
    AEXResponse aexResponseObj = null;
    Blob aesKey = Crypto.generateAesKey(256); // Random generated value
    Blob initialVector = Crypto.generateAesKey(128);// Random generated value 
    System.debug('aesKey :::'+ EncodingUtil.base64Encode(aesKey) )  ;
    System.debug('initalVector ::: '+EncodingUtil.base64Encode(initialVector)  );
    try {

        // Build AEX request JSON
        String requestJSON =  JSON.serialize(aexRequest, true);  
        System.debug('### requestJSON :: ' + requestJSON);

        // Build Authorization string
        General_Settings__c userName = General_Settings__c.getValues(Constants.AEX_USER_NAME);
        General_Settings__c companyKey = General_Settings__c.getValues(Constants.AEX_COMPANY_KEY);  
        String authorization = 'Basic ' + EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(userName.Value__c+':'+companyKey.Value__c));

        // Build Http request
        HttpRequest httpRequest = new HttpRequest();  
        httpRequest.setEndPoint(Label.AEX_EndPoint); 
     //  httpRequest.setEndPoint('https://requestb.in/zno8xizn');
        httpRequest.setMethod(Constants.Method_Post);  
        httpRequest.setHeader(Constants.Content_Type,Constants.Content_Type_Json);
        httpRequest.setHeader(Constants.Authorization, authorization);
        httpRequest.setHeader(Constants.Key, encryptMyKeys(aesKey));
        httpRequest.setHeader(Constants.Iv, encryptMyKeys(initialVector));
        System.debug('requestJSON @@'+requestJSON);
        httpRequest.setBody(encryptRequest(requestJSON,aesKey,initialVector));
        httpRequest.setTimeout(Constants.Timeout);
        logger = new API_Utils_Logger(httpRequest, Constants.AEX_Publish_Api_Name);

        // Http request to AEX  
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpResponse httpResponse = http.send(httpRequest);
        String responseJSON = httpResponse.getBody();
        responseJSON = responseJSON.replaceAll('""', 'null');
        System.debug('### responseJSON :: ' + responseJSON);

        // Parse AEX Response JSON
        aexResponseObj = (AEXResponse) JSON.deserialize(responseJSON, AEXResponse.class);

        System.debug('### aexResponseObject :: ' + aexResponseObj);

        // Insert the record in API log object for success and failure scenario
        logger.createLogWithStatusCode(responseJSON , false, 200);

    }catch(Exception e){            
        // Log the exception in API Log Object
       // logger.createLogWithStatusCode(e.getMessage(), true, 500, 'Class Name : SubmitAgreementAPIService', 'Method : Post', 'Apex');  
        System.debug('## Exception Occured during Publish Opportunity data for underwriting API call : ' + 'Line Number' +e.getlinenumber()+ 'Exception: ' + e.getTypeName() + ': ' + e.getMessage() + ' -- ' + e.getCause()+'##'+e.getStackTraceString());
        throw e;
    }

    return aexResponseObj;
}   

  /*********************   
*@description :This method accept the parameter in string and encrypt based on AES -256 algorithm. The private key shared by AEX and will read from custom setting  
 *@param: accept the parameter which needs to be encrypeted in AES -256
*@return :  Return encrypted value , which will be sent over header which can't be breached when we transmit.
*@example:
**********************/
public static String encryptRequest(String jsonRequestBody,Blob aesKey, Blob initialVector ) {     
    Blob jsonRequestBodyObject = blob.valueOf(jsonRequestBody);
    Blob encryptedData = Crypto.encrypt(Constants.Advanced_Encryption_Standard, aesKey, initialVector, jsonRequestBodyObject);       
    return EncodingUtil.base64Encode(encryptedData);   
}   


public static String encryptMyKeys(Blob keyValue) {    
  //  String modules = '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';              
  //  String exponent = '65537';  
   String modules = '';
   String exponent = '';

   List<EncryptKeys__mdt> moduleList = [select AEX_MODULE_EXPONENT_FROM_PEM_FILE__c from EncryptKeys__mdt where EncryptKeys__mdt.MasterLabel='AEX_MODULE_FROM_PEM_FILE'];
   List<EncryptKeys__mdt> expoentList = [select AEX_MODULE_EXPONENT_FROM_PEM_FILE__c from EncryptKeys__mdt where EncryptKeys__mdt.MasterLabel='AEX_EXPONENT_FROM_PEM_FILE'];

    for(EncryptKeys__mdt moduleObject :moduleList){
       modules = moduleObject.AEX_MODULE_EXPONENT_FROM_PEM_FILE__c; 
       break;
    }

    for(EncryptKeys__mdt expoentObject:expoentList ){
       exponent = expoentObject.AEX_MODULE_EXPONENT_FROM_PEM_FILE__c;
        break; 
    }

    System.debug('modules ## '+modules +' exponent @@ '+exponent );


    String encModules =  EncodingUtil.base64Encode( EncodingUtil.convertFromHex(modules) ); 
    RsaEncryptionInitialSubmissionApi  rsa = new RsaEncryptionInitialSubmissionApi(encModules ,exponent);
    String  encryptedKey = rsa.encrypt(EncodingUtil.base64Encode(keyValue));
    return encryptedKey ;
}
```

---

public with sharing class RsaEncryptionInitialSubmissionApi{

```
private String modulus;
private String exponent;

// Hex digits
private static final String DIGITS = '0123456789abcdef';
private static final Decimal HEX_BASE = 16;

public RsaEncryptionInitialSubmissionApi(String modulus, String exponent) {
    this.modulus = modulus;
    this.exponent = exponent;
}

public String encrypt(String input) {
    Blob mod = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(modulus);
    //Blob exp = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(exponent);
     System.debug('mod size ::'+mod.size());
    // Pad password.nonce
    Blob pn = Blob.valueOf(String.fromCharArray(pkcs1Pad2(input, mod.size()-1)));

    Decimal modDec = hexToDecimal(EncodingUtil.convertToHex(mod));
    Decimal expDec =decimal.valueOf(exponent);// hexToDecimal(EncodingUtil.convertToHex(exp));
    Decimal pnDec = hexToDecimal(EncodingUtil.convertToHex(pn));

    System.debug('modDec :::: '+modDec );
    System.debug('expDec :::: '+expDec );

    // Calcluate padded^exp % mod and convert to hex
    Decimal result = modPow(pnDec, expDec, modDec);
    String hexResult = decimalToHex(result);
    // If length is uneven, add an extra 0
    if ((hexResult.length() & 1) == 1) {
        hexResult = '0' + hexResult;
    }

    // Generate the data to be encrypted.
    Blob encodedData = EncodingUtil.convertFromHex(hexResult);
    return EncodingUtil.base64Encode(encodedData);
}

@testVisible
private static Decimal hexToDecimal(String hex) {
    Decimal result = 0;
    integer length = hex.length();
    integer i = 0;
    while(i < length) {
        integer hexByte = DIGITS.indexOf(hex.substring(i, i + 1).toLowerCase());
        i++;
        result += hexByte * HEX_BASE.pow(length - i);
    }
    return result;
}

@testVisible
private static String decimalToHex(Decimal d) {
    String hex = '';
    while (d > 0) {
        Decimal digit = modulus(d, HEX_BASE); // rightmost digit
        hex = DIGITS.substring(digit.intValue(), digit.intValue() + 1) + hex; // string concatenation
        d = d.divide(16, 0, RoundingMode.FLOOR);
    }
    return hex;
}

// base^exp % mod
@testVisible
private static Decimal modPow(Decimal base, Decimal exp, Decimal mod) {
    if (base < 1 || exp < 0 || mod < 1) {
        return -1;
    }

    Decimal result = 1;
    while (exp > 0) {
       if ((exp.longValue() & 1) == 1) {
           result = modulus((result * base), mod);
       }
       base = modulus((base * base), mod);
       exp = exp.divide(2, 0, RoundingMode.FLOOR);
    }
    return result;
}

// dividend % divisor
@testVisible
private static Decimal modulus(Decimal dividend, Decimal divisor) {
    Decimal d = dividend.divide(divisor, 0, RoundingMode.FLOOR);
    return dividend - (d * divisor);
}

// Pad using PKCS#1 v.2. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS_1
// s = String to pad
// n = bytes to fill must be bigger than s.length()
@testVisible
private static List<integer> pkcs1Pad2(String s, integer n) {
    // Byte array
    List<integer> ba = new List<integer>();
    // Fill array with zeros to get the right size
    for(integer i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        ba.add(0);
    }
    integer i = s.length() - 1;
    while(i >= 0 && n > 0) {
        ba.set(--n, s.charAt(i--));
    }
    ba.set(--n, 0);
    while(n > 2) { // random non-zero pad
        // Since the array is converted to a string, choose integers that corresponds
        // to a proper char code see http://www.asciitable.com
        integer rnd = Math.round(Math.random() * (127 - 32) + 32);
        ba.set(--n, rnd);
    }
    ba.set(--n, 2);
    ba.set(--n, 0);
    return ba;
}
```

}